# How can i login in instagram with python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, instagram

Nowdays i am trying to make a simple python program that logs you into your instagram with requests library but it always prints wrong even when the pass is right thats the code.

```
import requests
url = 'www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax'
values = {'username' : 'USERNAME',
          'password' : 'thepassword'
try:
    session = requests.session()
    session.post(url, data=values)
except:
  print("wrong")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply making a `POST` request with username and password won't log you into Instagram. There are many other parameters you would need to post along with it. Though it is possible to do this with `requests` (by tracking network requests and then making `POST` requests according to it), there are far better options like using the [`selenium`](https://www.seleniumhq.org) library.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chromedriver")

try:
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login")
    login_credentials = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    "._2hvTZ.pexuQ.zyHYP")
    login_credentials[0].send_keys("ENTER YOUR USERNAME")
    login_credentials[1].send_keys("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD")
    click_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "._0mzm-.sqdOP.L3NKy").click()
    print "LOG IN SUCCESS"
except:
    print "SOMETHING WENT WRONG"
```

You can make the browser headless if you don't want a browser to open. Instagram is decrypting its API. However, there are many private [Instagram APIs](https://github.com/adarshpunj/Instagram/) available on Github.

Answer (score -2):

You have to [register your app](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/) and then use the token you get as a token in [every request](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

> **I WOULD NOT SUGGEST DOING THAT**, as [Instagram is changing its API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) to the [Instagram Web API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api).

Comment: so what do you suggest me to do

Comment: I'd suggest using the new API instead

Comment: sorry i am new to stack overflow